# NSAppleScript with administrator previleges fails when application is launched from package maker

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, applescript, packagemaker

I have a MAC OSX cocoa application,where i used NSAppleScript to run some script with administrator privileges .The application works fine when it is launched manually or from any other script .

But NSAppleScript doesn't launch the intended script when i tried to launch the application from package maker .

I have made a postflight script to launch the application from package maker .

Postflight:

`#!/bin/sh
open pathOFApp`

**NSAppleScript usage:**

```
NSDictionary *error = [NSDictionary new];


NSAppleScript *appleScript = [[NSAppleScript new] initWithSource:@"do shell script \"pathOFScript \" with administrator privileges"];

if ([appleScript executeAndReturnError:&error]) {
          NSLog(@"-----success --------");
```

}

```
else{
    NSLog(@"-------Failure-----");
```

}

Please help to fix this .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know the answer with applescript/PackageMaker, but have you tried using the unix security tool to launch your executable? I think it's been available since 10.5. You can probably combine this and your executable in one statement too.

```
/usr/bin/security execute-with-privileges /path/to/executable
```

Comment: I added the line what you suggested in a script and called that script through NSTask . The GUI hangs after asking the password.In GDB i can see YES(0) .

Comment: I never used this so you'll have to play with it to get it to work right. Google for examples.

Answer (score 0):

Got the solution for this .Since postflight script is launched with the root permission by packageMaker it was creating some permission issue with the NSAppleScript . Launching the application as "sudo open MyApp" in postflight will resolve the issue.